# jQuery - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'typeahead'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement the `typeahead` autocomplete search feature but having no luck. I am about two weeks new to jQuery, so I am not really sure which direction to go. Here is the error I am receiving in Chrome's debugger when the page loads

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'typeahead' ... BankListMaster:17
```

This refers to the first line inside this block of code after the declarations

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (term, process) {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/Home/GetNames")';

                return $.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {
                    return process(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The `typeahead` feature is being used inside a search bar with the following code. FYI - the `<ul class="nav">` tag that is truncated simply contains a large number of `<li>` elements. Just shortened it for readability.

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">  
          <div class="navbar-inner">  
            <div class="container">  
            <ul class="nav"> ... </ul>  
        <ul class="nav"> 
        </ul>  
            <form class="navbar-search pull-left">  
              <input type="text" value="" id="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" class="search-query" /> @*placeholder=" Agent search" />*@  
            </form>  
        <ul class="nav pull-right">  
          <li>@Html.MenuLink("Help", "About", "Home")</li>  
        </ul>  
            </div>  
          </div>  
        </div>
          <li>@Html.MenuLink("Help", "About", "Home")</li>  
        </ul>  
            </div>  
          </div>  
        </div>  
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
                var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
            })();  
        </script>
```

EDIT

I've also tried the following two declarations, plus any number of combinations of the three (i.e. the `http` link) and receive the same error

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/typeahead.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/typeahead.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

SECOND EDIT

Changed the jQuery version and `typeahead` file to the following and am still getting the same error...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-typeahead.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly linked the typeahead script?

Comment: Are you sure that your code is loading the typeahead js?

Comment: I've tried actually downloading the files and adding them to the project and received the same message. However, to answer your question... like I said I've used jQuery for about two weeks now and am not 100% sure these declarations are correct. If I navigate to the twitter github page I can view the code, and I've downloaded and added the .js files to the project correctly.

Comment: typeahead.js has a dependency on jQuery 1.9+ while your code says jquery-1.8.3. See [link](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js)

Comment: I changed the tag to the following `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and still no luck. Is the `.min.js` going to be different that the same version without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the cause of this problem was still, but these declarations solved it. I'll leave this question unanswered for awhile in case someone sees the problem.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blattchat.com/demos/typeahead/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
```

Comment: You were loading the typeahead script before you declared jquery UI. the typeahead dependends on the query UI. thats why re-ordering solved the issue.